# InDesign: Placing one XML information in multiple fields

Tags: xml, adobe, adobe-indesign

I have a little questions about InDesign and XML.

I have a simple XML file like this:

```
<product>
<name>...</name>
<price>...</price>
</product>

<currency>EUR</currency>
```

I have imported this into InDesign and everything works fine so far. I've assigned the `price` tags for each product to the corresponding text fiels in the document and encountered a little problem while trying to assign the `currency` tag:

I want to assign the single `currency` tag to several text fields as I obiously want to have the same currency after all prices (in my case: EUR). But InDesign does not let me do that, if I assign the tag to one text field and go on and asign it to another, it deletes the tag from the first text field I've added it to.

I've tried copying the text field es well and this seems to create new XML information in the XML sidebar. So far so good, but if I make a change to the XML information on my source file now, it entirely deletes all the copied text fields with that information.

Any suggestion on how to make this work? Only thing I found on google was assigning multiple XML tags to one text field, but that's not what I'm searching for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here but it also depends on how dynamic is the currency info. If you are always using EUR, you can either use a script to add the EUR at the end of your price tags or change the layout so the "EUR" string is part of the layout to be repeated. Or XSLT on the fly to change the XML structure so that the currency is automatically placed at the right place or duplicated.
Could you give a richer sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input xml structure is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>A</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    
    <product>
        <name>B</name>
        <price>20</price>
    </product>
    
    <currency>EUR</currency>
</products>
```

Then a xslt like :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="curr">
            <xsl:value-of select="*/currency"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/product">
             <product>
                <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="price">
                    <xsl:with-param name="curr">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$curr"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                </product>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
        </products>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="price">
        <xsl:param name="curr"></xsl:param>
        <price>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$curr"></xsl:value-of>
        </price>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would output :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>A</name>
        <price>10 EUR</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>B</name>
        <price>20 EUR</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following xsl would add a currency node inside each product node just after the price node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="local-name()='price'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//currency[1]"/>    
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

InDesign provides an option to apply an xsl while importing xml.

If you prefer to append the currency string to the end of the price string you could use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="price">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ',//currency[1])"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```